# See the plot close to the intersection

Tags: r

```
## Define the moment generating function of Weibull distribution
scale <- 1/2
shape <- 1 
lambda <- 2 
beta <- 0.1

## I have specified nmax=160 since I cant perform the sum until infinity
mgfw <- function(x){
  nmax <- 160
  scale <- scale
  shape <- shape
  suma <- 0
  for(n in 0:nmax){
    suma <- suma + ((x^n) * ((scale)^n)) * gamma(1 + (n/shape)) / factorial(n)
    }   
  return(suma)
  }  

curve(mgfw, from=0.1, 0.25, ylim=c(1, 1.2))
mu <- (scale) * gamma(1 + (1 / shape))

fun2 <- function(x) 1 + x * (1 + beta) * mu

x <- seq(0, 10, length.out=100)  
y <- fun2(x)

curve(fun2, from=0, 10, add=TRUE)
grid()
```

Solving the previous equations I got the next results:

```
library(rootSolve)
r <- uniroot.all(function(x) mgfw(x) - fun2(x), c(0.1, 0.185))
r
abline(v=r)
```

I got a plot like this

[image]

The intersection of both lines is given by the vertical line. But I would like to get a plot where the intersection can be clear in the plot. How to resize the plot? Or see in the area with different scale?

Comment: Please format your code properly; use line breaks and indentations; as it stands right now, this is not valid R code (missing semicolons to separate multiple statements).

Comment: Can you not just add specific x/y-axis limits to `curve`; e.g. `curve(mgfw, 0.1, 0.25, ylim = c(1.1 - 0.005, 1.1 + 0.005), xlim = c(r - 0.005, r + 0.005))` will give a zoomed view around the intersection?